# AvalonEdit TextEdit Not Scrolling when used in a usercontrol inside Itemscontrol

Tags: wpf, avalonedit

I am using Avalon Edit control inside an itemscontrol. The scrollviewer is not scrolling when the cursor position changes. here is the code

UserControl1.xaml

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:avalonedit="http://icsharpcode.net/sharpdevelop/avalonedit"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="WpfApplication2.UserControl1"
x:Name="UserControl">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <avalonedit:TextEditor/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
xmlns:avalonedit="http://icsharpcode.net/sharpdevelop/avalonedit"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
x:Name="Window"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="640" Height="480">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="ItemsCtrlSteps">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:UserControl1/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Mainwindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ItemsCtrlSteps.DataContext = new List<string> { "a", "b" };
    }
}
```

And i dont want to show scrollbars inside each texteditor..please help!!